# Why is Halahala Poison the one that came out of Churning of Ocean depicted in Blue in Shiva's throat?

Tags: shiva, samudra-manthan

Why is Halahala Poison the one that came out of Churning of Ocean depicted in Blue in Shiva's throat? Any scripture backing to this?

Comment: From folklore, when Kaalakoota poison came about by churning, in order to to contain its destructive power Shiva could neither allow it outside ( the worlds would be poisoned) nor swallow it ( could start annoying insides of Shiva), so had to hold it in his throat in a sort of precarious balance.. which nevertheless turned his throat locally blue blood color.  (The poison itself is not of blue color).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inquiry is about the color of the KalaKuta poison and why it is  depicted  Blue in shivas throat?

The answer is the Kaalkuta poision which came out of Samudra manthan was not originally blue in color but because of it was the mala of the water it shown its effect on even Lord Shiva's throat.
According to [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01019.htm) the nature of the poison was as that a fire attended with fumes.

> अतिनिर्मथनादेव कालकूटस्तत : पर : | 
>  जगदावृत्य सहसा सधूमोsग्निरिव
>   ज्वलन ||41 ||
>
> P. 60 But with the churning still going on, the poison Kalakuta
>   appeared at last. Engulfing the Earth it suddenly blazed up like a
>   fire attended with fumes.

---

The answer is provided in Shrimad Bhagvatam as follows.

> तस्यापि दर्शयामास स्ववीर्यं जलकल्मष: । 
>  यच्चकार गले नीलं तच्च
>   साधोर्विभूषणम् ॥ [**SB 8.7.43**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/7/43/?query=8.7.43#bb49682) ॥
>
> tasyāpi darśayām āsa sva-vīryaṁ jala-kalmaṣaḥ 
>  yac cakāra gale
>   nīlaṁ tac ca sādhor vibhūṣaṇam
>
> As if in defamation, the poison born from the Ocean of Milk manifested
>   **its potency by marking Lord Śiva’s neck with a bluish line.** That line,
>   however, is now accepted as an ornament of the Lord.

The blue color of Lord Shiva's throte became his ornament afterwards. So the poison  was not of blue color but due to it's  effect , Lord Shiva's throat became blue. So the throat is depicted as blue and not the poison.